# How do I monitor display :1 while I'm using display :0?

Tags: x11, x-server

I am running X on two displays. :0 is my primary display but I also have some programs running on :1. Is there any GUI application that will let me monitor display :1 in a window that sits on display :0?

(Using gnome, FWIW)

Comment: Monitor in what way? See it, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to see display :1 in a window that sits on display :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of 2 ways to do this when the system is remote, so given the 2nd X server is locally running on your system (:1) should really make no difference.

#### Method #1 - VNC

You could setup VNC on the 2nd X server and then run `vncviewer :1` from the 1st X desktop.

#### Method #2 - XDMCP

If you want to remote display an entire desktop from one system to another system you'd typically use [XDMCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29#X_Display_Manager_Control_Protocol). You can then use a tool such as [Xephyr](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Using_Xephyr) to connect to your 2nd X server on display `:1` from the 1st X server.

#### Example

```
$ Xephyr -ac -br -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
```

Here are several resources for setting up XDMCP and going further.

- [Configuring XDMCP and GDM on Red Hat Linux](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_ConfiguringXDMCPRedHatLinux.shtml)
- [xdmcp - Ubuntu wiki reference page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp)
- [Xdmcp - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdmcp)
- [GDM and XDMCP configuration for remote graphical Linux desktop access](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDM_XDMCP.html)

#### References

- [X display manager (program type)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29)